# How to keep top row when using order by

Tags: sql, oracle

| one | two |
| --- | --- |
| this | row |
| 1 | 2 |
| 3 | 4. |

So I want the above result, but when I use Order by Ascending, I get this (essentially, the words are at the bottom)

| one | two |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 |
| 3 | 4 |
| this | row |

Comment: How do you know which row is actually `this`?

Answer (score 2):

You can use VALIDATE_CONVERSION or REGEXP_LIKE to check whether the value of column one is number or not then order them according ly.

```
 create table testtable(one varchar(50),    two varchar(50));

 insert into testtable values('this'    ,'row');
 insert into testtable values('3'   ,'4');
 insert into testtable values('1'   ,'2');
```

Query#1:

```
 select * from testtable 
 order by (case when VALIDATE_CONVERSION(one AS NUMBER) = 1 then 2 else 1 end),one;
```

Output:

| ONE | TWO |
| --- | --- |
| this | row |
| 1 | 2 |
| 3 | 4 |

Query#2:

```
 select * from testtable 
 order by (case when REGEXP_LIKE(one, '^[[:digit:]]+$') then 2 else 1 end),one;
```

Output:

| ONE | TWO |
| --- | --- |
| this | row |
| 1 | 2 |
| 3 | 4 |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=dcfb0c54e18aba06b4535febd5283efe)*

Comment: in my opinion option 1 of this answer is a more reliable number <-> string differentiator than the accepted answer

Answer (score 1):

The issue is how numbers are sorted.  You could use:

```
order by (case when not regexp_like(one, '^[0-9]') then 1 else 2 end),
         one
```

This puts strings that start with non-digits first.

Comment: Would not work well if "this" was replaced by "1 car went left" for example. Option 1 of @Kazi...'s answer below is in my opinion a more reliable answer than this one.